# How to get rid of the blank space after transforming the UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, cgaffinetransform

My view hierarchy is the following:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is to transform eventsFiltersViewContainer (the highlighted view) outside the UIViewController by some amount (which in my case is the 'scrolled': the distance scrolled by the user). All that goes fine, except that if I do the transform animation I'm left with the blank space resulting in probably stack view (superview) not updating its frame. So, my question is - how do I make the proper transform, so that the events filters view container goes up and outside the view controller, but doesn't leave the blank space?

Here's my code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.0, options: [.showHideTransitionViews], animations: { [weak self] in
                    guard let self = self else { return }
                    let scrolled = scrollView.contentOffset.y - self.lastContentOffset
                    let top = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -scrolled)
                    self.eventsFiltersViewContainer.transform = top
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that a transform changes how a view is drawn, not where it actually is.

Comment: struggling to visualise what you are after, but if do understand if teels like you need to be animating a constraint change to move the view rather than performing a transform. (And if I'm not on your wavelength, sorry!)